# Need to create a Regular expression to Split String after first \r\n

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have been stuck in a situation .

Here are few input strings -

```
 "abacuses\r\n25"

"alphabet\r\n56,\r\n57"

"animals\r\n44,\r\n45,\r\n47"
```

I need the output to be splited like -

```
"abacuses\r\n25" to be splitted into A)abacuses B)25


"alphabet\r\n56,\r\n57" to be splitted into A)alphabet B)56,57


"animals\r\n44,\r\n45,\r\n47" to be splitted into A)animals B)44,45,47
```

So far I have tried this but it doesn't work-

```
string[] ina = Regex.Split(indexname, @"\r\n\D+");

string[] ina = Regex.Split(indexname, @"\r\n\");
```

Please Help

Comment: Ok, what about `"animals\r\n44,\r\n45,trees,\r\n47"`? Is it a possible type of input? If yes, what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No regex needed in your example. You basicaly parse string:

```
string input = "animals\r\n44,\r\n45,\r\n47";
var split = input.Split(new char[]{'\r','\n',','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var name = split[0];                        //animals
var args = string.Join(",", split.Skip(1)); //44,45,37
```

Many people use it for parsing, but Regex is not a parsing language! It is pattern matcher! It is used to find **substrings** in **string**! If you can just **Split** your string - just do it, really. It is much easier to understand than Regex expression.

Comment: In this case, you do not know if you remove a linebreak in between comma-separated numbers or not. The title suggests that it is not important, but the example is quite specific.

Comment: @eocron06 What a Life saver you are.Thanks

Comment: Just a note: this approach will lead to removing any standalone `\r` or `\n`, and cause unexpected results if they appear before `\r\n`. I agree it might not be that important here, but worthy of note.

Comment: Of course. There are 42 solution for this problem. We just represented 2 of them in total. 40 ways to go =)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to split a string at the first `\r\n`, you may use a [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) with a *count* argument:

```
var line = "animals\r\n44,\r\n45,\r\n47";
var res = line
    .Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// Demo output
Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
if (res.GetLength(0) > 1) 
    Console.WriteLine(res[1].Replace("\r\n", "")); // In the second value, linebreaks should be removed
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/v8ycqa)

The `2` in `.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` means that the whole string should be split into 2 parts only and since the string is processed from left to right, the split will occur on the *first* "\r\n" substring found.